# Web-Application and windows applications together

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, windows

I have one Web Application along with its set up and One Console Application.
Please let me know what shall be possible options where One installer includes both these Applications.

facing error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the quesion is "how to combine several applications in single installer" then answer is -- write installer using wix -- http://wix.sourceforge.net/
Using wix you define what files will be copied in what directories, what custom actions peformed, what shortscust created, what virtual directories and web application will be created.. and many more. Wix is most powerfull tool for creating installers (developed by Microsoft guys).